# ResponsiveSlides with pager like "1 of 5"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get http://responsiveslides.com to show a pager like "1 of 5".

Demo of pagers: http://responsiveslides.com/themes/themes.html

Html:

```
<ul class="product2_image1-rslides">
<li><img scr="1.jpg"></li>
<li><img scr="2.jpg"></li>
<li><img scr="3.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

And JS:

```
$(".product2_image1-rslides").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  speed: 500,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
});
```

Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: hi @DarrenSweeney off course I have read it. The thing is that it only shows the pager as bullets like: ( · ) (   ) (   ) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can us `pager: true` for numbers

```
$(".product2_image1-rslides").responsiveSlides({
  auto: true,             // Boolean: Animate automatically, true or false
  pager: true,
  speed: 500,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
});
```